# Persistent CSS Element editor for Firefox? (like Stylebot for Chrome)

Tags: firefox, css

[Chrome's Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha) allows you to right click any item in the page, and automatically create a CSS rule for that element. I'd like to have the same **for Firefox**.

I've tried [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/stylish/), but it adds so many annoying steps, since I have to "Inspect Element" with the default inspector, then figure it out how to call it in the CSS, then in the CSS fill everything manually …

Look at a couple of Stylebot screenshot to get an idea:

> [image: contextual menu]
>
> [image: edit stuff live]

It allows you to edit stuff live and see the preview while you're editing.

It doesn't *have* to have all the fancy visual options as Stylebot, it's fine as long as it lets me right click an element and have that element's name be pre-filled in the CSS: if then I have to manually set the CSS property, it's fine – assuming it previews them on-the-fly.

Now, I'm pretty sure there's nothing like that or I would have found it, but asking might bring unexpected results, and in future there might be an answer.

I want to keep the changes between reloads, so just modifying the CSS in Inspect Element is not sufficient.

Comment: In addition to Color That Site!, take a look at [User Style Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/user-style-manager/), which may have fewer steps than Stylish once you set it up. But it currently does not include functionality to select an element & automatically create a CSS template from it. You can use it in conjunction with [Element Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/element-inspector/) & [DOM Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/) to get closer to what you want, but not quite.  You would have to use copy and paste.

Comment: I just deleted my "Inspect Element" answer, please read the ["how to ask for alternatives" meta](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/94) before posting another question like this.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs I could never have guessed that being persistent wasn't an obvious feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Color That Site!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/color-that-site/) is quite good: not as complete as Stylebot, since its only goal is dealing with colours, but since that was the primary reason I using Stylebot anyway, that's good.

Actually, as far as changing the colours, is even more feature-rich than Stylebot.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot and elaborate a bit more on what it can do and what it can't?